# Extract key value from dataframe in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, jsonschema, key-value

I have the below dataframe which I have read from a JSON file.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"todo":["wakeup", "shower"]} | {"todo":["brush", "eat"]} | {"todo":["read", "write"]} | {"todo":["sleep", "snooze"]} |

I need my output to be as below Key and Value. How do I do this? Do I need to create a schema?

| ID | todo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | wakeup, shower |
| 2 | brush, eat |
| 3 | read, write |
| 4 | sleep, snooze |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key-value which you refer to is a struct. "keys" are struct field names, while "values" are field values.

What you want to do is called unpivoting. One of the ways to do it in PySpark is using [`stack`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack). The following is a dynamic approach, where you don't need to provide existent column names.

Input dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [((['wakeup', 'shower'],),(['brush', 'eat'],),(['read', 'write'],),(['sleep', 'snooze'],))],
    '`1` struct<todo:array<string>>, `2` struct<todo:array<string>>, `3` struct<todo:array<string>>, `4` struct<todo:array<string>>')
```

Script:

```py
to_melt = [f"\'{c}\', `{c}`.todo" for c in df.columns]
df = df.selectExpr(f"stack({len(to_melt)}, {','.join(to_melt)}) (ID, todo)")

df.show()
# +---+----------------+
# | ID|            todo|
# +---+----------------+
# |  1|[wakeup, shower]|
# |  2|    [brush, eat]|
# |  3|   [read, write]|
# |  4| [sleep, snooze]|
# +---+----------------+
```

Comment: used underscore instead of '.' dots in the column name due to an issue but this is leading to another error : extraneous input 'todo' expecting {')', ','}

Comment: `.` is not for name, it's for referencing struct fields. The dot doesn't go anywhere, after using it, the struct field is extracted. However, if you don't want to use it, there is one more option: instead of `.todo` you can use `['todo']`

Answer (score 1):

Use from_json to convert string to array. Explode to cascade each unique element to row.

data

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(('{"todo":"[wakeup, shower]"}'),('{"todo":"[brush, eat]"}'),('{"todo":"[read, write]"}'),('{"todo":"[sleep, snooze]"}'))],
    ('value1','values2','value3','value4'))
```

code

```
new = (df.withColumn('todo', explode(flatten(array(*[map_values(from_json(x, "MAP<STRING,STRING>")) for x in df.columns])))) #From string to array to indivicual row
   .withColumn('todo', translate('todo',"[]",'')#Remove corner brackets
              ) ).show(truncate=False)
```

outcome

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
|value1                     |values2                |value3                  |value4                    |todo          |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
|{"todo":"[wakeup, shower]"}|{"todo":"[brush, eat]"}|{"todo":"[read, write]"}|{"todo":"[sleep, snooze]"}|wakeup, shower|
|{"todo":"[wakeup, shower]"}|{"todo":"[brush, eat]"}|{"todo":"[read, write]"}|{"todo":"[sleep, snooze]"}|brush, eat    |
|{"todo":"[wakeup, shower]"}|{"todo":"[brush, eat]"}|{"todo":"[read, write]"}|{"todo":"[sleep, snooze]"}|read, write   |
|{"todo":"[wakeup, shower]"}|{"todo":"[brush, eat]"}|{"todo":"[read, write]"}|{"todo":"[sleep, snooze]"}|sleep, snooze |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: i changed my input quotes . Also, seeing an error data type mismatch in entries from argument 1 requires string type, however, '1' is of struct<todo:array<string>> type